# MySQL 8.0.22 regression in information_schema-related query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, information-schema

I have an `information_schema` query that works fine on MySQL 5.7.19, but behaves very strangely on MySQL 8.0.22.

The purpose of the query is to retrieve all column names, and, if a column is a FOREIGN KEY - then also return information about the tables/columns it references. I provide a simplified version below.

To reproduce, create a `dbg` database with a couple of tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbg;
CREATE TABLE dbg.Tbl1 (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE dbg.Tbl2 (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, tbl1Id int DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY tbl1Id (tbl1Id), CONSTRAINT Tbl2_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (tbl1Id) REFERENCES Tbl1 (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The problematic `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT
    TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA AS dbName,
    TABLES.TABLE_NAME AS tableName,
    COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME AS columnName,
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME AS keyColumnName
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
LEFT JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS
    ON COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA = TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    ON KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA = COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME = COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME = COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE
    TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbg'
    AND TABLES.TABLE_NAME IN ('Tbl1', 'Tbl2')
```

On MySQL 5.7.19, I get a correct result:

[image]

On MySQL 8.0.22, I get an incorrect result:

[image]

However, if I remove `Tbl1` from the `WHERE` clause, by changing `AND TABLES.TABLE_NAME IN ('Tbl1', 'Tbl2')` to: `AND TABLES.TABLE_NAME IN ('Tbl2')`, then I get a correct result:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a MySQL bug? Is there a workaround?